# SQL Server date_format

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the function DATE_FORMAT in SQL Server

I want to change my now date to d-m-Y h:i

How to do

Comment: Your question is about mssql but you tagged it with `mysql`. It's quite disturbing.

Comment: Alternative I'd suggest is to leave the formatting up to the presentation layer - leave your database layer to return the data. After all, it doesn't know what purpose the data is used for and means you can have a single query for multiple places, where each place needs to apply a different format as it sees fit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The MySQL documentation for [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is pretty good.

```
select date_format(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i');
```

Comment: @Bharanikumar mistagged the question first, fixed the tag later, finally accepted an answer for the wrong tag. I wonder if he understand the difference in the fist place.

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid that, in SQL Server, giving format to a date is not as simple as it should. You end up doing stuff like:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 114)
```

You can find the reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx