# Convert DATE_FORMAT to SQL Server function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have migrated my database from mysql to SQL Server. When I run my query I get the error:

> 'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

This is the query, where I am trying to convert the date as it's saved in the database 2014/03/03 to 03/03/2014 (D-M-Y).

This is the query:

```
DATE_FORMAT(routines.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as Dato
```

Comment: My apologies if I have misunderstood you, but I sincerely hope you are not storing dates and/or times in SQL Server as `VARCHAR` (aka strings).  Choose an appropriate data type (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `SMALLDATETIME`, etc) and perform date formatting at the application level.

Comment: Store them as DATE!!!!! The format of how they are stored is completely irrelevant. Change that in the display layer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server date\_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014463/sql-server-date-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(12),getdate(),105)
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for the various options.

Comment: That worked. How can I convert the date to show as D/M/Y istead of D-M-Y ?

Comment: Use 103 instead of 105.   Check the link out, it shows you all of the values for formatting the date

Comment: @user3270211 only change that in the display layer. Store the date and time as `DATE`, `TIME`, or `DATETIME` the format does not matter.

Comment: how to specify column name like created_at, updated at?

Comment: select CONVERT(varchar(12),getdate(),105) AS Created_at

Answer (score 2):

I like to use it in the beginning of my query

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY --Day/Month/Year ... you can write YMD or another combination
```

Syntax:

```
SET DATEFORMAT { format | @format_var }
```

You can see examples in [microsoft techNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

If you want to use  **CONVERT**  in your **SELECT** clause you can use:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM (or PM) – Oct  2 2008 11:01AM          
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy - 10/02/2008                  
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02  
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```